# Pass an Url to image view through AFNetworkingLibrary

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, afnetworking

The project was created with xcode 4.3.
I have used AFNetworking Library (non-ARC) in this app.

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
 [exhibitPortraitImageView setImageWithURL:url];
```

Here, when I print a NSLog value, am getting the URL but the imageview is not displayed.

How can I solve this?

Comment: can you give me your url? I ll test it from my side

Comment: This is my url 
http://mdb.scicloudsolutions.com:8001/sites/default/files/genesis-book-of-beginnings.jpg

I have done with sample project, in sample project it's working fine but in my app it's not working

Comment: when I print NSLog, the url shows, I have that prefix in myurl when i prints the url it shows with prefix only
NSString *urlstring = @"http://mdb.scicloudsolutions.com:8001/sites/default/files/genesis-book-of-beginnings.jpg";

Answer (score 1):

**Your code is fine, problem is with URL.**

Your URL, don't have prefix, `http://`, I added it and the code is same as in quesiton.

```
 NSString *urlstring = @"http://mdb.scicloudsolutions.com:8001/sites/default/files/genesis-book-of-beginnings.jpg";
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
 [exhibitPortraitImageView setImageWithURL:url];
```

[image]

Here, you've three options to fix this,

1) If URLs are not coming from server (or some where else) you can fix it within the app, see how,

```
NSString *badUrlString = @"mdb.scicloudsolutions.com:8001/sites/default/files/genesis-book-of-beginnings.jpg";
NSString *goodUrlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@",badUrlString];
```

2) Or if its coming from server (or some where else) you can ask them to fix this from their side.

3) If its under 2nd option then, ask them if this will always happen (static) then you can also modify this from your side if server side developers not able to fix.

see this for more help, [Check string containing URL for "http://"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6537771/check-string-containing-url-for-http)

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

I also tried your url, it is working fine.

I loaded it as:

```
NSURL *correctURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mdb.scicloudsolutions.com:8001/sites/default/files/genesis-book-of-beginnings.jpg"];
_imgFromUrl.image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:correctURL]];
```

And the result,

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply, nearly 40 images am displaying.
To show the good performance am using AFNetworingLibrary.If am converting in to data format.. it takes time load all the images. I want to reduce the waiting period

Comment: @Hemang I have checked with all your answers but it's not updating in my application

Comment: I checked with `AFNetworking` too. What's the problem with you? any logs? @user2080945

Comment: This is my log statement..
url string :http://mdb.scicloudsolutions.com:8001/sites/default/files/genesis-book-of-beginnings.jpg
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstring];
[exhibitLandscapeImageView setImageWithURL:url]

but it's not updating

Comment: @user2080945, check if `exhibitLandscapeImageView` is not nil and also try deleting the app from device (or simulator) and recheck.

Comment: 1st time am not getting the image, when i navigate to other screens and come back then it's displaying
1st time exhibitLandscapeImageView.image = NULL am receiving.. and exhibitLandscapeImageView is not nil